# Running self or other program as sudo once my Python script knows the password?

Tags: python, linux, privilege-elevation

I'm researching on Linux hardening and found out that a script can escalate to root once it knows the sudo password of the user.

I want to make a POC.

How can a Python script escalate it self to root once it knows the `sudo` `password`? I'm assuming I would have to use `subprocesses`.

I'm not asking about getting the password. You have to assume that my script already has the password through any of the methods mentioned here https://superuser.com/a/793241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go down the `subprocess` route, then you can use the `-S` flag on `sudo` so that you can pass the password through `stdin`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'python', 'my_script.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(b'thesudopassword\n')
```

As far as I am aware it is not possible to elevate the UID of a currently running process to root, however. It would probably be much easier to just launch a new Python or other process as root, as in the example.